# Laravel show data in API and View with the same function in a controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

Is it possible to show return json data as the API response and use the same data for a view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

```
$data = ["a_variable" => "its_value"];

if (request()->wantsJson()) {
    return response()->json($data);
}

return view('someview', $data);
```

Assume the call returns `$data` with the response.

Comment: This is working. How did you test and what's the error you get?